# Why is the asterisk route always rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In the code below, `Page2` is always rendered whether I am on `Home` or `Page1`. Ideally, I want `Page2` to render only when the URL is not `"/"` or `"/pageone"`, kind of like a 404 page.

Why is this happening?

```
// Import stuff using this syntax specifically for CodePen
const { HashRouter, Route, Link } = ReactRouterDOM;

const Home = () => (
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <Link to="/pageone">Page 1</Link>
    <Link to="/pagetwo">Page 2</Link>
  </div>
);

const PageOne = () => (
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
  </div>
);

const PageTwo = () => (
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Page 2</h1>
  </div>
);

const App = () => (
  <HashRouter>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/pageone" component={PageOne} />
    <Route path="*" component={PageTwo} />
  </HashRouter>
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All routes alone inside a router will always be ***inclusively*** matched and rendered. In other words, any and all matches will be rendered. If you want to ***exclusively*** match and render routes then render them within the [`Switch`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) component. The `Switch` "renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location." Because of this you'll want to keep in mind that route path order and specificity (i.e. how specific the path is) matters and you'll want to order the routes from *more* specific paths to *less* specific paths.

```
const { HashRouter, Switch, Route, Link } = 'react-router-dom';
const App = () => (
  <HashRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/pageone" component={PageOne} />
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="*" component={PageTwo} />
    </Switch>
  </HashRouter>
);
```

Comment: does it make sense to have a `Switch` around all the routes in the app?

Comment: @asus Yes, if you want to only match one of them at-a-time. If you want a mixture of inclusively and exclusively matched routes then the routing configuration gets a little more complicated, but it's doable.

Comment: I see! I ask because I have some nest `Switch`es already but I think it's more of a test and fix scenario

Comment: @asus FWIW if you were using RRDv6 the [`Routes`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/routes) component is the spiritual successor to the `Switch` component (*it handles the route matching logic*) and it is ***required*** to wrap any `Route` components being rendered. Having a `Switch` wrapping all the root routes is completely natural.